# Calling another view using <id=" "> in Codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, codeigniter-3

How to call another view in view Codeigniter 3? I look for another project that using this method and I tried to use this script on view1

```
function loadData(args){
    $("#view2").load("<?php echo base_url('subfolder/controller/method'); ?>");
}
```

And my view1 contains

```
<div id="view2"></div>
```

In my view2

```
<div class="content table-responsive"><table>(this contain thead, foreach etc and some $a->name etc)</table></div>
```

My controller

```
public function method2(){
    $data['temporary'] = $this->Model->getAllData('temporary')->result();
    $data['limit'] = $this->Model->countAll('temporary');
    $this->load->view('view/view2', $data);
}
```

But it didn't show the table in view2 (assuming that I have the table on database filled) on the project I take for example, it's work.
How can I fix this?

Comment: what is the purpose of loading JS view ?? you can load it dynamically

Comment: So how are you displaying view1? Have you checked that the generated js has the correct url by viewing the html code using your browsers "ViewPage Source"? And that you have loaded jquery!